# Can MessageFilterExtension filter messages on watchOS as well?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I am currently working on a project involving MessageFilterExtension in the iOS framework to filter spam SMS. It works well on my iPhone and iPad, not showing notifications of the filtered messages and putting them in the "Junk" category in the Messages app. On Mac, it is also possible to disable notifications from unknown senders entirely, which is acceptable.

However, I am still getting notifications of the junk/spam SMS on my apple watch that are filtered on my iPhone.

Is it possible to leverage MessageFilterExtension (or some other mechanism) to prevent spam SMS notifications from appearing on the apple watch as well, or is this extension limited to the iPhone itself? My watch is set to mirror iPhone notifications, so it seems reasonable to me that the filtered messages should not send a notification on this device.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any solution for this? We noticed this behaviour on iOS 14/WatchOS 7